# Nautilus : Connect to server (ssh) can't find mounted fs in local files

Tags: server, mount, ssh, nautilus

With Ubuntu 22.04, when I use Nautilus to mount distant ssh server, I can't find anymore where it is mounted. "Open in local Terminal" has disappeared. There is only : "Open in remote terminal".
Previously (from 18.04 up to 21.10) distant server  was mounted in /run/user/1000/gvfs/{sshServerName}/
Is it somewhere else or mechanisms are differents ? Should I use sshfs instead to properly mount my distant server in the local file tree ?

Any information or idea ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`sudo apt remove fuse`
`sudo apt install fuse3`
`sudo apt install gvfs-*`

reboot and it's work again
I don't know what is really useful or not !

Answer (score 1):

Default in Ubuntu 22.04 gvfs-fuse package is not installed

```
# Install packages
sudo apt install fuse3 gvfs-*

# Reboot your machine
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that today the mounted volume is back in :
/run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host={serverName}
maybe an update ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is back again...
nothing in /run/user/1000/gvfs/sftp:host={serverName}
and I don't how I can access the mounted files in a terminal for example
I was working in the 6 June 2022.
Any Idea ?

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1232934)